# Interesting Buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, button, graphics

Is there a way, without having to create images of my own, to make rounded rectangle buttons look more appealing? For example, providing them with shading, or making them look three dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article I wrote recently: [UI Polish In An Instant](http://blog.hawkimedia.com/2011/11/ui-polish-in-an-instant/)

It talks about using layer properties to add visual interest to your UI with relative ease.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so, then consider creating a UIView with all your customizations enabling it for user interaction. It might help!

Comment: I would subclass `UIControl`, not `UIView`.  `UIControl` is more suited for buttons.

Comment: @sudorm-rf But Randolph is mainly looking for Visual customization!

Comment: `UIControl` inherits from `UIView`, so you can still customize the control just like a normal view.  But either way, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Using Core Animation functions you can make them a bit more exciting. First import the QuartzCore library. Then you can access properties of the view.layer.

button.layer.cornerRadius changes the rounded corners
button.layer.strokeWidth changes the border thickness
button.layer.strokeColor changes the border colour
button.layer.shadowColor use this and other shadow properties to add a nice soft drop shadow

There's a whole bunch of properties you can tweak if you check the CALayer documentation, and these work for any UIView or subclass, not just buttons.

To add a gradient, check out the CAGradientLayer. You can create one of these and append it as a sublayer to your button.layer.

There's also CAShapeLayer to add an arbitrary polytonal shape to your button, all drawn using code without any images.